# How to remove indentation in footnote?

Tags: footnotes, indentation

On the first page, I put "corresponding author" in a footnote.  However, there is unwanted indentation before `*` (see the picture below).

[image]

I tried `\noindent` but didn't work.  MWE is at below.  Thank you!

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{authblk}    
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{1} 
\title{\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textbf{The Title Here\\}\vspace{1ex}} 

    \author[1,*]{Author One}
    \affil[1]{\small University of California;}     

\date{}

\end{multicols}

\twocolumn[ 
  \maketitle
  \thispagestyle{fancy} 
        \begin{abstract}
         {\fontfamily{pnc}\selectfont 

         \textbf{} Following the first case series of Hodgkin lymphomas  \\
}
    \end{abstract}
]

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{*}
    \footnotetext{\noindent  Correspondence: John Doe, 1234 Main Street, City Name, CA 00000. Tel: 123-456-6666; Fax: 123-456-4545; Email: johndoe@thisu.edu}

\section{Introduction}
Although Pathology is as ancient as 17th century BC Egyptian medicine, Hematopathology can only be historically traced back to 1832 AD when Thomas 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 38):

cfr's solution clearly works.  For people without much experience like myself, I found a simpler solution from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842722/how-do-i-control-footnotes-indentation-in-latex) and would like to share here:

Use [footmisc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc?lang=en) package:

```
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
```

Comment: The thing is, you really shouldn't have explicit mark up in the arguments of macros like `\title`. That's why I used **titling**. But this conflicts with **authblk**. Also, as I read your question, you wanted this to apply to the footnote following the author name but not to all footnotes throughout the paper, whereas this use of **footmisc** will change all footnotes, I think. On the other hand, if that's wanted here, obviously **footmisc** is a better solution than mine. But you should still avoid explicit mark up in `\title` etc.

Answer (score 5):

Never use manual mark up in commands like `\title`. I'd suggest using something like **titling** here. I'm not sure if you really want what you seem to - it seems strange. But you can no doubt adapt:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 1ex}
\preauthor{\begin{center}
    \large \lineskip 0.5em}
\postauthor{\par\end{center}}
\thanksheadextra{1,}{}
\setlength\thanksmarkwidth{.5em}
\setlength\thanksmargin{-\thanksmarkwidth}
\begin{document}
\title{The Title Here}
\author{Author One \thanks{Correspondence: John Doe, 1234 Main Street, City Name, CA 00000. Tel: 123-456-6666; Fax: 123-456-4545; Email: johndoe@thisu.edu}}
\date{}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookd{%
  \begin{abstract}
    \fontfamily{pnc}\selectfont% This seems most unwise.
    \textbf{} Following the first case series of Hodgkin lymphomas
  \end{abstract}}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookc{%
  \begin{center}
    \textsuperscript{1}{\small University of California;}
  \end{center}}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}% really? Are you sure you want this?

\section{Introduction}
Although Pathology is as ancient as 17th century BC Egyptian medicine, Hematopathology can only be historically traced back to 1832 AD when Thomas

\end{document}
```

Note that normally you should select fonts for the whole document by loading the relevant package, if you wish to change the defaults. It is not wise to have an abstract in a different font, for example....

[image: sample]

Comment: your solution clearly works!

Comment: If you means this line of code `\title{\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textbf{The Title Here\\}\vspace{1ex}}`, the real file needs to show the type of paper (such as "Review", or "Article") on top of the title.  I forgot to trim down the code for MWE.  I know we should discuss something different from the topic.

Comment: `\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{<whatever>}` would be better. You shouldn't do explicit mark up in arguments like this. `\title{}` should just give the title. Or don't use `\maketitle` at all and just do it by hand. `\maketitle` is not compulsory.

Answer (score 2):

By `meho_r` on [Latex.org/forum](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11152)

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
\setlength\parindent{1em}%
\noindent
\mbox{\@thefnmark.~}{#1}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate dummy text

\begin{document}
Test\footnote{\lipsum[1]}.
\end{document}
```

Redefines `makefnttext`, setting the `paraindent` length and removing the indent with `\noindent`.