# Cannot create footnote without marker

Tags: footnotes

I am using this template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/aaai-2023-author-kit/wxnmhzcrjbpc and would like to remove the marker to my footnote.

I tried using the code from [Footnote without a marker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker) to remove the marker but it still did not work. You can see below that the "footnote without marker" still has the marker.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\noindent\makebox[1.8em][r]#1}
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

I cannot post a MWE here because there are several other files but here is the editable MWE https://www.overleaf.com/6147694589pmbfyhnqdrcy

Here is the MWE that I can post.

```
\def\year{2022}\relax
%File: formatting-instructions-latex-2022.tex
%release 2022.1
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article} % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{aaai22}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{times}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{helvet}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{courier}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{graphicx} % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\urlstyle{rm} % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\def\UrlFont{\rm}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{natbib}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS AND DO NOT ADD ANY OPTIONS TO IT
\usepackage{caption} % DO NOT CHANGE THIS AND DO NOT ADD ANY OPTIONS TO IT
\DeclareCaptionStyle{ruled}{labelfont=normalfont,labelsep=colon,strut=off} % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\frenchspacing  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
%
% These are recommended to typeset algorithms but not required. See the subsubsection on algorithms. Remove them if you don't have algorithms in your paper.
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\noindent\makebox[1.8em][r]#1}
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

% These are are recommended to typeset listings but not required. See the subsubsection on listing. Remove this block if you don't have listings in your paper.
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
    basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},% footnotesize acceptable for monospace
    numbers=left,numberstyle=\footnotesize,xleftmargin=2em,% show line numbers, remove this entire line if you don't want the numbers.
    aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt,%
    showstringspaces=false,tabsize=2,breaklines=true}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{listing}{tb}{lst}{}
\floatname{listing}{Listing}

\pdfinfo{
}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} %May be changed to 1 or 2 if section numbers are desired.
\title{}
\author{
    \blfootnote{footnote without marker}
}
\affiliations{
}

%Example, Single Author, ->> remove \iffalse,\fi and place them surrounding AAAI title to use it
\iffalse
\title{}
\author {
}
\affiliations{
}
\fi

\iffalse
%Example, Multiple Authors, ->> remove \iffalse,\fi and place them surrounding AAAI title to use it
\title{}
\author {
}
\affiliations {
}
\fi

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe that the marker is `\@thefnmark`. You might try locally defining it to be empty.

Comment: @rallg how do i do that. Do you have a code that I can copy paste?

Comment: You could try the solutions by [@Simon Dispa to my similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/675136/273733), they work for me in my documents, hopefully they can help too

Comment: Try `\setcounter{footnote}{-1}`.  (Not checked, not tested.)

Answer (score 0):

I use a different (custom) document class, so my code may not be entirely correct for the question. But this works in my custom class, so something similar should work for you:

The footnote marker is placed by `\@thefnmark`, which is in LaTeX base document classes. In the document body

```
This text has normal footnotes, with marker.
\begingroup%
\makeatletter\def\@thefnmarker{}\makeatother%
This text would have an empty footnote marker.
\endgroup%
This text has normal footnote marker. You may need to subtract 1 from the marker count.
```

Note the use of percent at the end of the code lines. That prevents extra paragraph breaks.

An alternative approach is to define two kinds of footnotes, using different macros. One kind has `\@thefnmarker` as part of its definition, and the other kind does not.